# Get most recent date, underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Got this:

```
 [{
  "title": "qq",
    "dateValuePair": {
      "date": "2016-04-29T22:00:00.000Z",
      "value": 243500.3491
     }
  },
  {
    "title_sv": "ccc",
    "dateValuePair": {
      "date": "2016-03-29T22:00:00.000Z",
      "value": 243500.3491
     }
 }]
```

I need a function that returns the object with the most recent date.

```
  {
    "title_sv": "ccc",
    "dateValuePair": {
      "date": "2016-03-29T22:00:00.000Z",
      "value": 243500.3491
     }
 }
```

Is there some neat one line underscore trick to do this?

Comment: [`arr.slice().sort((a, b) => +new Date(a.dateValuePair.date) < +new Date(b.dateValuePair.date))[0]`](https://jsfiddle.net/qjhbmt1k/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**_.max**](http://underscorejs.org/#max):

```
var array = [{
  "title": "qq",
    "dateValuePair": {
      "date": "2016-04-29T22:00:00.000Z",
      "value": 243500.3491
     }
  },
  {
    "title_sv": "ccc",
    "dateValuePair": {
      "date": "2016-03-29T22:00:00.000Z",
      "value": 243500.3491
     }
 }];

var result = _.max(array, function(el) { 
  return new Date(el.dateValuePair.date).getTime();
});
```

Comment: @knutole This is underscore, not lodash.

Comment: Right. Well, for those who use Lodash, note the difference. :)

Comment: I don't understand even my array elements is all strings "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" format, why can't they just sort it in strings type and return the highest in string value.  That lost me!

Comment: for `lodash` need to use `_.maxBy` instead